# Different size of serialized array of enum values in Java

Tags: java, arrays, enums

I have enum `MyEnum` with values `A`, `B`, `C`. Each of this values has size 60 bytes (when I write value to byte array).

Then I have array of length 3 with these enum values. However, size of array depends on values in the array:

```
import java.io.*;

enum MyEnum {
    A, B, C
}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        System.out.println(sizeOf(MyEnum.A)); // 60
        System.out.println(sizeOf(MyEnum.B)); // 60
        System.out.println(sizeOf(MyEnum.C)); // 60

        MyEnum[] values = { MyEnum.A, MyEnum.B, MyEnum.C };
        MyEnum[] values2 = { MyEnum.B, MyEnum.B, MyEnum.C };
        MyEnum[] values3 = { MyEnum.B, MyEnum.B, MyEnum.B };

        System.out.println(sizeOf(values)); // 110
        System.out.println(sizeOf(values2)); // 105
        System.out.println(sizeOf(values3)); // 100
    }

    private static long sizeOf(Object object) throws IOException {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream oOut = new ObjectOutputStream(bOut);
        oOut.writeObject(object);
        oOut.close();
        return bOut.toByteArray().length;
    }

}
```

Is there any way to convert array of enum values to byte array with always same size? I would like to size of `values`, `values2` and `values3` to be same.

Comment: The size difference is probably because duplicate objects in `ObjectOutputStream` are not written multiple times but only referenced the second and later times. So sending `A, B, C` needs to send 3 objects and `B, B, B` will send 1 object and 2 references. Why does the exact size being identical matter so much?

Comment: I would like to create file in which I can read nth record (in this example array) with complexity O(1). So if I want record on index 1234, I can easily use file.seek(1234 * recordSize) and read one record.

Comment: That'll run into many separate problems with standard serialization, the current one is just one of them. Maybe a custom serialization format is better suited for this task.

Comment: When you know you are going to store and retrieve constants of a particular `enum` type only, just store their [`ordinal` number](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#ordinal--) as an `int` or even as a `byte` when there are less than 256 constants. You can not seek to an arbitrary position in an `ObjectInputStream`.